# How can I change Column Headers title from SQL query datagrid in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid

I have already a code to display a table on a datagrid via a SQL query...

```
con.Open()
sql = "Select roomnumber, type, status, rate, [max], start, [end] FROM rooms where [end] = @endfirst OR [end] = @endsecond "
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endfirst", ender)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endsecond", minus)

da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds)

GridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
ds = Nothing
da = Nothing
con.Close()
```

I was wondering how I can change the column Header titles, I already did some research by I really can't figure it out.

Any tricks on how I can achieve this?

Side note: I am currently using ms access yet once my program is release I will be using a MySQL database that's why I am doing this SQL query to datagrid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using Alias for each field? `Select roomnumber As Room_Number, etc`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: thank you so much... it works... it really advances when you knew the term to search...

Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome, I made it the answer if you don't mind selecting it! =)

Comment: Sure, its okey. I was going to tell you to do it... Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Alias for each field. [SQL Alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

```
Select roomnumber As Room_Number, etc
```

Comment: That doesnt change the datagridview headers that just aliases the column header. Try doing: "Room Number" as an alias. To change the column headers properly would be: datagridview.columns(0).headertext= "something"